# Is it possible to get the value of normal function in $(document).ready(){});

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a normal function and $(document).(ready(){});.

```
$(document)(ready(){
console.log("Function called on startup")
$('#tab').on('click',function(){
console.log("get the value of "+**i**)
 });
  });
```

**Normal function**

```
var i="";
var sendvalue = function(){
   i ="hectic";
 }
```

I need to get the value of i in the document.ready function. I tried but i am not able to get it.
I understood that the document.ready function will load initially as the page loads. After, that any  other way is to there to get the value of i in the document.ready function.

Comment: if you want to get the updated value of `i` then somebody have to call the method `sendvalue`, is there anybody calling that method?

Comment: No, that method is not called. Since, the variable i is declared as  a global variable I am calling that variable directly.

Comment: Your `ready` statement is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually calling the function to get the value anywhere. Add a call to it like this:

```
$(document)(ready(){
  console.log("Function called on startup")
  sendvalue();
  $('#tab').on('click',function(){
    console.log("get the value of "+**i**)
   });
});
```

Comment: The variable i is declared as a global variable only know, it is not possible to get the value of i directly instead of calling the function.

Comment: Your function `sendValue` does not return a value. If you want to get a value from `sendValue`, you need to change `i = "hectic";` to `return "hectic";`, then calling `sendValue()` will give you your value.